# Laravel Simple File Manager

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, vue.js

How can I show files and folder recursively. Like if I set a directory/path that will load inner folder and files of that folder.

I need simple file manager for browser files and folder , not EL-Finder like one.

Answer (score 0):

I use Laravel file manager

[Laravel file manager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager)

Comment: Want to implement new one, for this reason i don't want to use large repository